# Comparing elements of matrix of different Sizes dimension in Matlab

Tags: matlab, compare

Can anybody help me to find out the method to compare the elements of
different sized matrix in Matlab ?

I have one matrix `A` (100×10) with random elements.

The second array has some of elements which are in matrix `B` (1×10) with random elements.

Let's say element of matrix `A(i,j)` and `B(i,j)` is element of `B`.

So I want to compare `B(i_1,j_1)` is equal `A(i_1,j_1; i_2,j_1; i_3,j_1;.....; i_100_j_1)`
in these two matrices, i.e, we need to compare first row, first column of matrix `B` and all row, first column of matrix `A`.

If they are equal - `1`, if not equal - `0`. And they will be new matrix `C`.

The elements are **numbers** not strings.

**What function can i use in this case if wanna again compare A and B1 (Like B) is 10x1 matrix too ? Perhaps i will add B2, B3..and so on.**
plz help me.

Regards,
Kyaw Kyaw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a case for `bsxfun`:

```
C = bsxfun(@eq, A,B);
```

Comment: Thank you! Rody Oldenhuis :)

Comment: What function can i use in this case if wanna again compare A and
B1 (Like B) is 10x1 matrix too ?
Perhaps i will add B2, B3.

Comment: @user3455066: `cellfun(@(x) bsxfun(@eq, A, x), B, 'UniformOutput', false)` if you put all matrices, `B1`, `B2`, etc. in a `cell`-array `B = {B1 B2 ...}`